# Ruby bundler statement in boot.rb file in Rails App root folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, boot

I found the below given statement in boot.rb file inside the root folder of my Rails Application.

```
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)
```

Can anyone help me to understand the usage of `ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE']` and `||=` in this context?

Thank you.

Comment: I would be comfortable with a rails specific answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ENV` is a hash. `BUNDLE_GEMFILE` is an item in that hash. `||=` known as "or equals" operator, what it does is checks if `ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE']` is set, if it is, then it takes the same. But if it isn't, then it assigns whatever the function `File.expand_path()`returns to `ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE']`.

Comment: Hancic: May I ask you just for clarification that 'ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE']' is only just an array like any other arrays that we create? or any other special meaning it has?

Comment: ENV is just an array yes (unless rails does some magic behind the scenes that I'm unaware off).

Comment: I don't understand. When I run ENV.class in the Rails console it says: Object. Doesn't it behave more like a Hash than an Array?